# fgets() segmentation fault caused by newline character

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I am using fgets() to obtain input from stdin. I want fgets() to continue obtaining input from the user until the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (EOF) command is executed. After the end of the file is reached, the array of user input should be printed.

When the user enters a newline (\n) between two lines of input, a segmentation fault occurs when I try to print the array. I have looked at similar StackOverflow posts, in addition to tutorialspoint descriptions, but I could still use some help in figuring out this problem.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Maximum input size
    int input_size=1024;
    // Standard Input array
    char standard_input[input_size];
    // Input array
    char **input=malloc(input_size*sizeof(char*));
    // Integer to track input size
    int size=0;

    // Handle the input
    while(fgets(standard_input, input_size, stdin)){
        // Delimiter
        char delimit[]=" \n";
        // Node string
        char *my_node;
        my_node=strtok(standard_input, delimit);
        // Process the input from stdin
        for(int i=0; my_node!=NULL; i++){
            input[i]=malloc(strlen(my_node)+1);
            strcpy(input[i], my_node);
            // Special input processing
            // Ignore non-alpha entries
            // Convert uppercase to lowercase
            bool valid=true;
            for(int j=0; j<strlen(input[i]); j++){
                // Ignore non-alpha entries
                if(!isalpha(input[i][j]))
                    valid=false;
                // Convert uppercase to lowercase
                else
                    input[i][j]=tolower(input[i][j]);
            }
            my_node=strtok(NULL, delimit);
            // If the element was found to be invalid due to the presence
            // of non-alpha characters, remove it
            if(!valid){
                free(input[i]);
                i--;
            }
            else if(valid)
                size++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%s\n", input[i]);
    // Memory cleanup
    // Free input to avoid memory leaks
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        free(input[i]);
    }
    free(input);
    return 0; // return 0 to match the return type of the main function
}
```

Comment: What happens if `strtok` returns `NULL`?

Comment: Also, use a *debugger* to catch the crash in action, and locate where in your code it happens and check what the values of all involved variables are. If you still can't solve your problem then edit your question to give us those details (crash location and variable values).

Comment: `for(int i=0; my_node!=NULL; i++){
            input[i]=malloc(strlen(my_node)+1);strcpy(input[i], my_node);` : When inputting multiple lines, `i` is reset line by line. So `size` does not match.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, that worked. Thank you very much.